# Skip reference file validation for typescript

Tags: typescript, configuration, reference

SmartClient now provides a reference file for typescript to get a code completion. I have to put next line to the begin of my typescript file

```
/// <reference path="path/to/isomorphic/system/development/smartclient.d.ts"/>
```

And it works - VSCode shows code completion hints, but when I compile my my typescript file tsc looks like also does a validation of that "smartclient.d.ts" and prints a huge amount of errors to the console.

Is it possible to configure somehow typescript to disable validation of reference file without breaking code completion?

I tried to put option "noResolve": true, but then code completion does not work.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable type checking of declaration files you can use `skipLibCheck` compiler option.

Pay attention - it will skip type checking of **all** declaration files.

[Compiler Options reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)